# Instantiating Null Objects with ?? Operator

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following typical scenario:

```
if(anObject == null)
{
 anObject = new AClass();
}
```

I'm wondering what is thought of the following replacement using the ?? operator:

```
anObject = anObject ?? new AClass();
```

I'm not sure whether I should be using the second form. It seems like a nice shorthand, but the anObject = anObject construct at the beginning seems like it could be a bit of a code-smell.

Is this a reasonable thing to do, or is there a better shorthand that I am missing? Or maybe, "It's three lines, get over it!"?

Comment: If it would be a code smell, it wouldn't be introduced in the first place. The second form is more concise and should be preferred.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: The question is *not* whether the `??` operator is code-smell, but whether its use in an expression that is assigned back to what is passed as one of its operands is code-smell.

Comment: Actually, this is four lines...

Comment: What I've never understood is why there's no `x ??= y;` operator, equivalent to `x = x ?? y;`. There's `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, etc...

Comment: But you _don't_ have `anObject = anObject` at the beginning.  You have an assignment with `anObject` on the left and `anObject ?? new AClass()` on the right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**

As O. R. Mapper has pointed out, the question is to do with whether the self-assignment is a code-smell. This is 6 and two 3s in my book. Assignment is hardly an expensive operation, and you do it in other areas at any rate with most math operators.

I tend to think it isn't a code smell.

---

I do that all the time for lazy objects (a slight variation on your example):

```
return _myClass ?? (_myClass = new MyClass());
```

I think it's fine. Oddly enough I don't tend to use `Lazy<T>`... not sure why, but then again I don't very often make lazy items. `Lazy<T>` is more expressive in its intent, as in, you can read that the item is lazily instantiated, but technically it adds another `object` overhead to an existing item. I don't really worry about that either way really.

As for "getting over it", I think this probably falls into that category. Each to their own in this case I think.

Comment: Thanks a very nice idea I will mark the answer after 12 min I cannot now thanks.

Comment: I do not claim any of these is code-smell. In my above comment, I'd just like to point out that whether or not *"it" has been introduced* - *it* being the `??` operator - is irrelevant, as the question does not wonder whether the operator itself is code-smell, but the particular way to use it shown in the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sorry I will re-word, what I meant to say is you highlighted that the question was about self-assignment and whether that was a code smell. My bad.

Comment: Tip: Use the `Lazy<T>` constructor that takes a `Func<T>` delegate (lambda) if your class's constructor might throw an exception. That will cache and rethrow your exception, where the no-arg constructor would throw a TargetInvocationException. (Better - avoid throwing exceptions from constructors.)

Answer (score 6):

Without assigning the result of the expression back to the same variable - e.g. `a = b ?? new AClass();` - that pattern is fine and it serves for something like a "fallback" new default instance:

```
private MyClass anObject;

// ...

(anObject ?? new MyClass()).DoSomething();
```

In this case, the newly created object is not stored for later reuse.

When assigning to the same variable, it looks like you're initializing something lazily, in which case using [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) would be the more expressive way to go:

```
private Lazy<MyClass> anObject = new Lazy<MyClass>();

// ...

anObject.Value.DoSomething();
```

The instance will be created at latest when the last line executes.

Comment: Although I agree `Lazy<T>` is more expressive and obviously designed for the task, I wince a little when I read "the preferred way to go" as if it has been universally agreed.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: You're right, I've improved my choice of words in the answer.

Comment: +1 for that correction. I usually tend to stay out of "best practice" questions, but I felt this one was more harmless than most. You tend to cop a lot of flak if you go against the "norm" :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    AClass anObject = null;

    // option A
    if (anObject == null)
    {
        anObject = new AClass();
    }
    // option B
    anObject = anObject ? new AClass();
}
```

Comparing option A with option B's optimized IL code:

```
Option A                            Option B                            Description
IL_0000:  ldnull                    IL_0000:  ldnull                    // Push a null reference on the stack.
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // anObject   IL_0001:  stloc.0     // anObject   // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0.
IL_0002:  ldloc.0     // anObject   IL_0002:  ldloc.0     // anObject   // Load local variable 0 onto stack
                                    IL_0003:  dup                       // Duplicate the value on the top of the stack.
IL_0003:  brtrue.s    IL_000B       IL_0004:  brtrue.s    IL_000C       // Branch to target if value is non-zero
                                    IL_0006:  pop                       // Pop value from the stack
IL_0005:  newobj      AClass..ctor  IL_0007:  newobj      AClass..ctor  // Allocate an uninitialized object or value type and call ctor
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // anObject   IL_000C:  stloc.0     // anObject   // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0.
```

As you can see there is very little difference between the two - Option B (using the ternary operator) results in a couple more stack operations.

Unless your computer runs on clockwork you won't see any difference in your final code so as with many things - **do whichever is the most readable for *your* code**.

Comment: So is this just saying that coalesce operator produces more concise IL? Not sure how this alone without an explanation answers anything, let alone how it got upvoted twice...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of patterns that I have seen used in WPF view models (which is where I see this pattern used mostly):

Method 1 non-Lazy:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly SomeValue _value;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _value = new SomeValue();
    }

    public SomeValue Value { get { return _value; } }
}
```

Method 1 Lazy:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Lazy<SomeValue> _value = new Lazy<SomeValue>(() => new SomeValue());

    public SomeValue Value { get { return _value.Value; } }
}
```

Method 2:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private SomeValue _value;

    public SomeValue Value { get { return _value ?? (_value = new SomeValue()); } } 
}
```

The major differences between method 1 and method 2 are when and how the object gets created. Method 1 lazy uses `Lazy(T)` which adds overhead to the creation. It's only really necessary for large objects and WPF models tend not to do too much heavy lifting. Large objects can take advantage of laziness internally to keep object creation reasonable.

Method1 lazy and method 2 are very useful for when the view is large. The UI should be kept responsive, so deferring object creation provides a better user experience. When large objects are involved with a complex view this will prove necessary.